# Real-Time chat app using laravel as backend API and react js as frontend

Tags: reactjs, laravel, frontend, backend

is it possible to make realtime chat app with laravel and react js

I already made the api for creating conversation and sending/getting messages

how can I make the communication between backend and frontend realtime ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Echo https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting and use socket.io to handle the communications with the frontend but if I would recommend using a better stack for a chat, you can easily set up your own https://www.ejabberd.im/ Server :) and you will get a more reliable chat